# Why TCP handshake is not happening while using sockets in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I tried implementing socket server and clients using c#, I noticed that TCP hand shake has not happened and the data flows from the very first send/receive. is this usual socket behavior? or the methods Send and Receive hide the handshake implementation?

Note: opened a socket using below code.

`IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, portNumber);
Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listener.Bind(endPoint);`

Comment: Define *TCP hand shake* and how you are determining if it happened (or not)

Comment: Any transport level details are handled by the `Socket` implementation; you don't need to call a handshake method explicitly, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for your comment. Lately i tried implementing a websocket server using TcpListener (which i am 100% sure uses sockets underneath)  in which i explicity handled TCP handshke process. Might be, i was able look into the details because it was an upgrade from http to WebSockets which is not the case for this question.

Comment: @Michael I already raised my doubt if the handshake process is abstracted in socket methods.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I believe by handshake he means the client can't connect to the server. Please see my answer.

Comment: Did you call `Listen` on the `listener` as shown in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.listen?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @Wyck my answer addresses that :)

Answer (score 0):

You have binded the socket to a address but haven't actually started listening for connections yet. You need to call `Listen()` to actually listen for connections.

According to the documentation:

> "If you are using a connection-oriented protocol such as TCP, your server can listen for connections using the Listen method."

Use the following code:

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, portNumber);
Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listener.Bind(endPoint);
listener.Listen(1);
```